# Why this iOS implemtation of DesEncrypter doesn't produce the same result as Java?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, encryption

Here is the Java **PBEWithMD5AndDES** implementation algorithm.

I'm **looking the exact equivilent in objective-C** for the iOS platform without using any external libraries. The accepted solution should only rely to libraries included in the iOS SDK.

The Java below encrypts **"bar"** with passphrase **"foo"** as **"0WUc+boDvbU="**

```
new DesEncrypter("foo").encrypt("bar") == "0WUc+boDvbU="
```

But the obj-c code encypts **"bar"** with passphrase **"foo"** as **"VRWOhmfj2g8="**

```
 NSString* encrypted = [ self encrypt:@"bar"]; == "VRWOhmfj2g8="
```

What I'm looking is the obj-c encrypt method to encrypt "bar" as "0WUc+boDvbU=" just like the Java one.

Java code:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;


public class DesEncrypter {
    private Cipher ecipher;

    private Cipher dcipher;

    private byte[] salt = {(byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x1B, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0x5e,
            (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0x12};

    public DesEncrypter(String passphrase) throws Exception {
        int iterationCount = 2;
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
    }

    public String encrypt(String str) throws Exception {
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(ecipher.doFinal(str.getBytes())).trim();
    }

    public String decrypt(String str) throws Exception {
        return new String(dcipher.doFinal(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str))).trim();
    }
}
```

Obj-c code

```
- (NSString*) encrypt:(NSString*)encryptValue {
    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize = [encryptValue length];
    vplainText = (const void *) [encryptValue UTF8String];
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSizeDES) & ~(kCCBlockSizeDES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);
    unsigned char salt [] =  {0x10,0x1B,0x12,0x21,0xba,0x5e,0x99,0x12};
    NSString *key = @"foo";
    const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
    ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,kCCAlgorithmDES,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,vkey,kCCKeySizeDES,salt,vplainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,(void *)bufferPtr,bufferPtrSize,&movedBytes);
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    NSString *result = [myData base64Encoding];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I always use RNCryptManager - it's not exactly the same implementation, but it's a start. https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely/tree/master/iOS/Classes/RNCryptor

Comment: DES is generally not recommended for new systems.  It should only be used if compatibility with an old system is required.  Otherwise use AES for new systems.

Comment: @rossum thank you but I still need the DES implementation in obj-c for the iOS platform

Comment: the encrypt function in unistd?

Comment: can I ask why the downvotes? It's a solid question.

Comment: There are easily a dozen ways to make "identical" encryption setups produce different results -- buffer sizes, salt, etc.  In the above case it's not at all obvious that the two keys are identical.

Comment: @HotLicks both methods use "foo" as a passphrase. You mean is not obvious from the wording or there is something wrong with the code?

Comment: The first one runs the key through two conversions.  It's not clear that the second one does any such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to prepare your key as it is requited in this algorithm. If we do this, output is the same as in Java version.

```
- (NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)encryptValue {
    // first of all we need to prepare key with md5
    // setup md5 context with salt and key
    NSString *key = @"foo";
    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    memset(md5Buffer, 0, CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH);
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CC_MD5_CTX md5Ctx;
    CC_MD5_Init(&md5Ctx);
    CC_MD5_Update(&md5Ctx, [keyData bytes], [keyData length]);
    unsigned char salt[] =  {0x10,0x1B,0x12,0x21,0xba,0x5e,0x99,0x12};
    CC_MD5_Update(&md5Ctx, salt, 8);
    CC_MD5_Final(md5Buffer, &md5Ctx);

    // do md5 hashing
    CC_MD5(md5Buffer, CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, md5Buffer);

    // our key is ready, let's prepare other buffers and moved bytes length
    NSData *encryptData = [encryptValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    size_t resultBufferSize = [encryptData length] + kCCBlockSizeDES;
    unsigned char resultBuffer[resultBufferSize];
    size_t moved = 0;

    // DES-CBC requires an explicit Initialization Vector (IV)
    // IV - second half of md5 key
    unsigned char IV[kCCBlockSizeDES];
    memcpy(IV, md5Buffer + CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH / 2, sizeof(IV));

    CCCryptorStatus cryptorStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmDES,
                                        kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, md5Buffer,
                                        CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH/2, IV,
                                        [encryptData bytes], [encryptData length],
                                        resultBuffer, resultBufferSize, &moved);

    if (cryptorStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [[NSData dataWithBytes:resultBuffer length:moved] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Output: 0WUc+boDvbU=

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of misinformation about encryption, and I don't want to spread any more. However, what I'm going to say here is *MOSTLY* true, with some slight simplifications to limit scope and keep it concise.

When you encrypt and decrypt text with any type of encryption, you generally start with a password of some sort. Contrary to popular belief, that password does not unlock anything. Instead, the password is combined with other factors (Salt, Initial Vectors, Hashing, etc) to generate and encryption key. The specifics of going from the password to the encryption key are the Key Diffusion Algorithm. It is common for the same encryption algorithm, such as AES or DES, to have different Key Diffusion Algorithms in different platforms. It is unfortunate because that means that data encrypted on one platform cannot be decrypted on another.

That does not mean the task is impossible. It only means you must find compatible implementations or settings when working cross platform.

Comment: mostly true, but still interesting. i'm pretty sure that it is possible to decrypt/encrypt aes independently from the platform, but i have no idea about des.

Comment: You are correct that AES can be decrypted on any platform. The issue is finding compatible key diffusion algorithms. Using standard libraries on .NET, iOS, and Android, there are compatible algorithms on any 2, but I never found one for all 3. I would love to be proven wrong about this. I don't know how much that applies to DES, but I would advise against DES use anyways.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that String.getBytes() will return a byte[] in the default charset of the platform.  Better to use String.getBytes("UTF-8")

The java code has number of iterations set at 2, I don't see that in the objective c version.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The Java code cannot be changed. The boundy will be awarded to the answer that provides a obj-c method producing the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, have you tried different padding options on iOS? it looks like the current padding you are using is kCCOptionPKCS7Padding. It is a simple change and maybe will provide some addition information...